# Hide Results, W3Schools PHP Example AJAX Live Search

Tags: php, html, ajax, live, show-hide

I am playing with the Ajax Live Search functionality from the W3Schools website. It is working fine except I would like the results div, #livesearch, to hide again when the user clicks away from it. I have found an example piece of code which does this but I cannot comdine the two successfully. If I add the code the search results can be hidden when the user clicks away but the user has to click first to see them, which obviously wont work.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp
http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/676788-hide-div-tag-if-outside-div-clicked

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I got it to work by using this,

    $(document).click(function(e){
         var elem = $(e.target).attr('id');
         if(elem !== 'livesearch'){
             $('#livesearch').fadeOut('fast');
         }
    });

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the javascript 'onblur' event.

You could create a new function which cleared the div:

```
blurFunction() {
document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = ''
}
```

The onblur event:

```
<input type="text" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)" onblur="blurFunction()" />
```

EDIT: Actually I just noticed the showResult function already caters for clearing the div, so just insert:

```
<input type="text" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)" onblur="showResult('')" />
```

Comment: I think OP was looking to hide the entire div and have it reappear on events, rather than clearing the innerHTML text. I might be reading it wrong though.

Comment: Hi Steve. The onblur showResult function works correctly and hides the results div when you click away however it has the unfortunate consequence of making the link inside the result block also unclickable. Is there a way around this? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I got it to work by using this,

    $(document).click(function(e){
         var elem = $(e.target).attr('id');
         if(elem !== 'livesearch'){
             $('#livesearch').fadeOut('fast');
         }
    });

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right, you want the dropdown to disappear when the input loses focus and reappear when the mouse is moved over it, not just clicked?

I was able to achieve this by using an onblur event to hide the box (your example that you found works equally well, I believe). `onblur="hide(this)"` to hide the dropdown div. Hide js function is the same: `function hide(id)
{
document.getElementById("livesearch").style.display = "none";
}`

To make it reappear on mouseover, I added an `onmousemove` event to the input: `<input type="text" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)" onblur="hide(this)" onmousemove="showResult(this.value)" />`
.

*Most importantly* I added this line `document.getElementById("livesearch").style.display = "block";` in the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()` to make the div reappear.